# sed to replace a,0,0 into a,b,c in a file

Tags: sed, replace

Assuming we have

```
a,0,0
```

in a csv file

I would like to replace all of them into

```
a,b,c
```

I have tried the following and none of them works.  The command just halt there without generating any output.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

```
sed -i 's/a,0,0/a,b,c/g' input_file.csv > output

sed -i -e 's/\a,0,0\/\a,b,c\/g' input_file.csv > output
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the sed man page to see what `-i` does? The 2nd script makes no sense btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just should eliminate the `-i` option or just use it.

So in your case, to redirect the output of your `sed` command you need to use:

```
sed 's/a,0,0/a,b,c/g' input_file.csv > output
```

`-i` option means **inplace**, so if you use, it will overwrite your original file.